# How to give a user x full access to a directory?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, filesystem, directory

In Ubuntu 18.04, how can I give a user `x` a full access (read/write/execute) to a directory and all its content?

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you give a little more information about what exactly you are trying to do, but...

Ubuntu by default uses Owner-Group-All permissions.  I am assuming that you want "User-X" to have access to a directory that it owned by "User-Y"

First, Create a group for "User-X" and "User-Y", and add those users to the group - replace `<userGroupName>` with a name that makes sense to you

```
sudo groupadd <userGroupName>
sudo usermod -a -G <userGroupName> User-X
sudo usermod -a -G <userGroupName> User-Y
```

Secondly, change the group ownership of the directory in question

```
sudo chown User-Y:<userGroupName> <directoryName>
```

Where `<directoryName>` is the directory that you are working upon

Finally, change permissions at the directory to allow the owning group, (`<userGroupName>`), appropriate permissions.

```
sudo chmod g+rwx <directoryName>
```

If the group is non-empty, you may wish to change the permissions of all files and folders in the directory:

```
sudo chmod g+rwx -R <directoryName>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-R` (recursive) option to the `chown` and `chmod` commands, for example you could do something like this:

```
chown -R x directoryname
chmod -R u+rwx directoryname
```

The `chown -R` command then sets the user x as the owner of that directory and everything inside. The `chmod -R u+rwx` command grants the owner read, write, and execute permission for that directory and everything inside.